# How to pass a url query string containing another url with query strings

Tags: java, spring, url

I'm building a service that takes a complete url as a parameter and then processes the CSV data pointed by that url. So I want to pass the the url of the CSV file as a single parameter after my service url. The whole url I really what it to work is like following,

http://mydomain.com/myservice?CSVUrl="http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=FB&d=1&e=10&f=2014&g=d&a=4&b=18&c=2012&ignore=.csv"

I hope my Java Spring MVC controller can work in following way. The issue is, the CSVUrl string I want to pass as a parameter contains special characters and other query strings that are supposed to be kept as a whole string for the CSVUrl. In addition, the CSVUrl is supposed to be something given by users. So I don't know it in advance. It also give me difficulty to encode it before passing it in the url.

```
public ModelAndView processCSVFile(@RequestParam String CSVUrl) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    CsvDataProcessor csvDataProcessor = new CsvDataProcessor();
    String vizData = csvDataProcessor.getVizDataTableString(CSVUrl);

    mav.addObject("csvData", csvData);
    mav.setViewName("myservice.jsp");

    return mav;
}
```

It does not work in this way. How can I make it work? As I searched, I may need use URLEncoder and URLDecoder. But have not figured out how to make it work. Appreciate for any help in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please have a look at [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html), for example:

```
URLEncoder.encode("mysite.com?a=foo&b=cow", "UTF-8");
```

Should give you `mysite.com%2Fa%3Dfoo%26b%3Dcow`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it requires I know the passed url in advance, right? What if I don't know it in advance?

Comment: Then you can pass a variable containing the user input